# .net6.0 - write forward - AWS Aurora: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Our AWS RDS (Aurora MySQL 2.10.2) has a primary cluster and a secondary cluster.

Secondary cluster is a replica and has a reader instance. **This reader instance is set to read_only false** and I have setup write-forwarding from secondary to primary cluster. So, I have set the parameter group's variable `init_connect` to value `set @@aurora_replica_read_consistency=SESSION`

When I connect to secondary cluster's reader endpoint through MySQL Workbench then write-forwarding works i.e. if I issue query to create record in secondary cluster, it gets write-forward to primary and querying same table shows the new record.

However, the problem occurs with my .net6.0 application. If I point my .net6.0 application, which uses [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), to same secondary cluster's reader endpoint in connectionstring then it does not work and it fails with this error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 954
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 44
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 127
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 456
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 330
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 323
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Since parameter group variable on secondary cluster `init_connect` is set to value `@@aurora_replica_read_consistency=SESSION`, it should technically work.

When I look for ready_only variable details on secondary cluster then I see it is set to false:

```
show global variables like 'read_only%';

Variable_Name   Value
read_only       OFF
```

Does anyone know if I am missing something here?

**Update**

In my .net6.0 application, if I explicitly execute `set @@aurora_replica_read_consistency=SESSION` before SaveChanges(), I get a different error. This concurrency error seems misleading since I'm the only one connected to secondary cluster.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagationAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Sniffing MySQL traffic from application, I noticed that this SaveChanges() issues a UPDATE statement along with `select ROW_COUNT();`. When ROW_COUNT() executes, it returns 0 which causes above exception and then the transaction rollbacks.

Comment: Did you have any joy resolving this ?

Comment: I did. There are many different issues in this question. Is there any specific part you are stuck on?

Comment: The issue i'm seeing is that row_count() returns zero, when i expect it to return 1.
When running the same statement in mysqlworkbench against the readonly node with write forwarding i get row_count = 1 when updating a row, but not in EF.
I have got round it by creating a custom implementation of IModificationCommandBatchFactory and essentially disabling the concurrency check, however this is not ideal - i would like to understand why row_count() from inside EF returns zero but not when i run the sql directly myself - and how i could get this to work as expected.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with RDS where row_count() does not recognize the immediate previously executed DML command. We have ticket opened with AWS but their response is that don't know when they'll have any answer for us. Our workaround for this problem was to use IDBCommandInterceptor and implement its ReaderExecuting and ReaderExecutingAsync methods. In that, we split the queries to execute separately and for second part of the query (select), do a SuppressWithResult.

Comment: For example an update query is followed by select query having row_count(). When implementing ReaderExecuting, grab DBCommand.CommandText and split UPDATE query to execute first then do a SuppressWithResult on the second part of query using same DBCommand object. Somehow RDS likes this and produces correct results.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the reply, I will give that a shot.

Comment: @soccer7 - Any chance you can provide some example code for how you split the UPDATE query and used SuppressWithResult? I am running into a similar issue when the generated SQL is trying to execute a series of multiple DELETE commands, each followed by SELECT ROW_COUNT();

Comment: Amazon has acknowledged that Aurora Global DB replication + write forwarding does not currently support multi-statement SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the value of the variable from your app, using the `DbContext` that fails to change the records:

```cs
var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    connection.Open();

var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select @@read_only;";

var result = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
Trace.Assert(result == 0);
```

You also want to check the connection string that is used by the open connection and ensure, that it is expected.

Comment on your results or update your question and we'll take it from there.

Comment: The connection string is correct and `select @@read_only` returns 0. Also updated the question with some additional findings.

Answer (score 0):

@soccer7's solution solved this problem for me

You need to implement a `DbCommandInterceptor`, split EF's query, execute the query and `SuppressFinalize` `SELECT ROW_COUNT();`

This is my solution:

```
public class ForwardWritesCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    private const string UPDATE_COMMAND = "SELECT ROW_COUNT();";

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        if (ShouldSplitQuery(command.CommandText))
        {
            return SplitUpdateQueryAsync(command).Result;
        }
        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    public override async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (ShouldSplitQuery(command.CommandText))
        {
            return await SplitUpdateQueryAsync(command);
        }
        return await base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    private bool ShouldSplitQuery(string query) => query.Trim().EndsWith(UPDATE_COMMAND);

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute the UPDATE part of the query, then SuppressWithResult the SELECT part
    /// </summary>
    private async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> SplitUpdateQueryAsync(DbCommand command)
    {
        command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Substring(0, command.CommandText.LastIndexOf(UPDATE_COMMAND));
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        command.CommandText = UPDATE_COMMAND;
        return InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(await command.ExecuteReaderAsync());
    }
}
```

Register this in `services.AddDbContext`:

```
services.AddDbContext<FooContext>(options => 
...
    options.AddInterceptors(new ForwardWritesCommandInterceptor());
);
```